# React clear local state in other component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react. I'm created 2 components: Board and List. When I clicked on board then showing list of List components. For example, I change local state in List component (clicked on Show all), then clicked on other board - the local state "Show all" saved in other container on the same place. Why? This is reuse of components or not? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add the code for Board and List react classes, it is unlikely anyone will be able to give meaningful answers without code to look at.

Comment: Thanks. It's my mistake). I'm looping lists and set "key" for each component as index key: `<List  list={list} key={index} /> )}`  Now I change index as key= {index + list.id }: `<List  list={list} key={index + list.id} /> )}`